# Adding parameters to SSM maintenance window task

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-ssm

I'm trying to use the SSM Run Command by executing a script in S3 - I've tested this all works manually now I'm trying to code it.

I'm stuck with adding parameters to an SSM manintenance window task.

Following this example - https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ssm_maintenance_window_task

Here is the snippet below. I'm adding 3 parameters and plan/apply runs fine but the changes are not reflected in the console!

```
 resource "aws_ssm_maintenance_window_task" "task" {
  max_concurrency = "2"
  max_errors      = "1"
  task_arn        = "AWS-RunRemoteScript"
  task_type       = "RUN_COMMAND"
  window_id       = aws_ssm_maintenance_window.taskuploadmaintenancewindow.id

  targets {
    key    = "WindowTargetIds"
    values = [aws_ssm_maintenance_window_target.taskuploadmaintenancewindowtarget.id]
  }

  task_invocation_parameters {
    run_command_parameters {
      parameter {
        name   = "SourceType"
        values = ["S3"]
      }
      parameter {
        name   = "SourceInfo"
        values = ["{\"path\":\"https://mybucket.s3.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/myscript.sh\"}"]
      }
      parameter {
        name   = "commands"
        values = ["myscript.sh"]
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out.. It's a bit silly but those parameters need to be camel case &  'commands' needed to be commandLine

The way I worked this out was to go back into SSM Run Command, build out a new command and scroll to the bottom and review the syntax of the AWS CLI config it builds for you:

```
  aws ssm send-command --document-name "AWS-RunRemoteScript" --document-version "1" --targets '[{"Key":"tag:Name","Values":["deliberately removed"]}]' --parameters '{"sourceType":["S3"],"sourceInfo":["{\"path\":\"https://mybucket.s3.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/myscript.sh\"}"],"commandLine":["myscript.sh"],"workingDirectory":[""],"executionTimeout":["3600"]}' --timeout-seconds 600 --max-concurrency "50" --max-errors "0" --region ap-northeast-1
```

So now changing the case/commandLine works. I hope this helps someone one day.

```
run_command_parameters {
      parameter {
        name   = "sourceType"
        values = ["S3"]
      }
      parameter {
        name   = "sourceInfo"
        values = ["{\"path\":\"https://mybucket.s3.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/myscript.sh\"}"]
      }
      parameter {
        name   = "commandLine"
        values = ["myscript.sh"]
```

Answer (score 0):

By the way, I found out that instead of dealing with the horrendous format when inputting sourceInfo, you can wrap it in jsonencode in Terraform.

```
  parameter {
    name = "sourceInfo"
    values = [jsonencode(
      {
        owner      = "ownername"
        path       = "pathdir"
        repository = "reponame"
        tokenInfo  = "sometoken"
      }
      )
    ]
  }
```